# Is there a way to provide bigquery data to external clients, filtering only their respective data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

Scenario:

Imagine that i have multiple clients data on bigquery and need to provide a way to they have access to their data, only their data. How can i provide this access with less effort?

i was thinking in create a python api and based on the bearer token, using a db with token -> client, find what is the client that owns that token and pass some filter arguments to the bigquery api, returning the filtered data.

But i really don't know if isn't there a easier way resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

````
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# TODO(developer): Choose an existing topic.
# project_id = "your-project-id"
# topic_id = "your-topic-id"
# subscription_id = "your-subscription-id"
# filter = "attributes.author=\"unknown\""

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

with subscriber:
    subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(
        request={"name": subscription_path, "topic": topic_path, "filter": filter}
    )
    print(f"Created subscription with filtering enabled: {subscription}") ```
````

Comment: thanks Aris, but i didn't understand how it can help me, can you provide more information about it, please?